# How to get number of elements in array of textbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, textbox

I have created a javascript in which when we click "Add" button, it adds textboxes with similar name, which creates a list of textboxes. 
The textboxes have code like below

```
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[]" id="my_textbox" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[]" id="my_textbox" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[]" id="my_textbox" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[]" id="my_textbox" />
```

The reason why I have given name as "my_textbox[]" is because this gets submitted to php code which then pretends these textboxes as array.

Now I would like to know the number of textboxes generate. It would be best if I can get the count through jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
alert($('input[name="my_textbox[]"]').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

first, each id shall be unique, else javascript will break.

```
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[]" id="my_textbox1" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[]" id="my_textbox2" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[]" id="my_textbox3" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[]" id="my_textbox4" />
```

for what you want:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

 var nbtextbox = $('input').length;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_textbox').length
```

You could also use:

```
$('#my_textbox').size()
```

which is functionally equivalent, but [the former is preferred](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

Comment: would both of them not give 1 as the count as you are referring the id

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the count -

```
alert($("input[name='my_textbox[]']").length)
```

you might want to change the ids of the input added making them unique.

Answer (score 0):

Working link http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/5vUDZ/

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    var iptCount= $("input[name='my_textbox[]']").length;
    alert(iptCount)

});
```